# Export Email Address and Mobile Number from Office 365 Distribution Group

Tags: powershell, export

I can't seem to find a way to export an email address and a phone number from a specific DG.

Hey guys,

I'm trying to get an email and a phone number from each member in a DG. I can't get the phone number.

I used any words I could think of

```bsh
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DG -ResultSize Unlimited | Select PrimarySMTPAddress, Mobile, MobilePhone,
Phone, PhoneNumber, MobileNumber
```

I also tried

```bsh
Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId | select DisplayName, MobileNumber
```

Nothing yields results. If I try the same comment with a simple `Get-MsolUser` it WILL work. Why?

It's this field in the Exchange admin:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: If I remember right you have to query the AD for these attributes. The only phone - related attribute you can get from the Exchange cmdlets should be `Phone`.

Comment: ... and BTW: the names of the attributes are: HomePhone, MobilePhone, OfficePhone and telephoneNumber.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the Exchange cmdlet `Get-DistributionGroupMember` returns an array of [ReducedRecipient member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/ff346107(v=exchg.150)) objects where not all AD user properties are stored.
In order to get the user properties you need, you will also have to use either the `Get-ADUser` or the `Get-MsolUser` cmdlet.

The code below uses `Get-ADUser` (untested)

```
$result = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DG -ResultSize Unlimited | 
    Where-Object { $_.RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAcountName -Properties MobilePhone, HomePhone, OfficePhone
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'DistributionGroup'  = $DG
            'DisplayName'        = $_.DisplayName
            'PrimarySmtpAddress' = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
            'MobilePhone'        = $user.MobilePhone
            'HomePhone'          = $user.HomePhone
            'OfficePhone'        = $user.OfficePhone
            'City'               = $_.City
            'Country'            = $_.CountryOrRegion
        }
    }

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path ('D:\DistributionGroupMembers_{0}.csv' -f $DG) -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

<sup>In order to use the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet you need to `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`.</sup>